# Am I allowed to start a sentence with "Composed"?

Tags: word-usage, past-participles, sentence-starts

> - **Composed** of an assortment of ten libraries including inhibitor library, stem cell signaling compound library, and anti-cancer compound library, among others, our bioactive screening libraries are ready-to-use chemical libraries for drug discovery, drug target identification, and other pharmaceutical-related applications.
> - **Being composed** of an assortment of ten libraries including inhibitor library, stem cell signaling compound library, and anti-cancer compound library, among others, our bioactive screening libraries are ready-to-use chemical libraries for drug discovery, drug target identification, and other pharmaceutical-related applications.

Am I supposed to start a sentence with "composed"?

Comment: Composed of is better construction...

Comment: Why wouldn't you be allowed to start a sentence with *composed*?

Comment: You may be thinking of the rule agaianst *dangling participles*, which says that if you do start with a participle, you must remember to put the subject before any other noun; *i.e.* not **Composed of an assortment, I think our libraries are the best*.

Comment: Minus 1 for verbosity. See below.

Answer (score 1):

Both are perfectly fine. The first is a bit cleaner. If you don't want to start with "composed", say "Because they are composed of". "Among others" is also redundant -- it's already clear from "including" that the list is not exhaustive.

My personal preference would be:

> Because they are composed of an assortment of ten libraries, including an inhibitor library, a stem cell signaling compound library, and an anti-cancer compound library, our bioactive screening libraries are ready-to-use for pharmaceutical-related applications such as drug discovery and drug target identification.

Comment: An opening subordinate clause of 26 words, and a total sentence length of 46 mostly technical words, hurts my brain.Think of your reader! For effective comprehension, it is best to get to the point and write in 'thought-bursts'. How about:'Our bioactive screening libraries are ready to use for pharmaceutical-related applications such as drug discovery and drug target identification. There are ten in all, including an inhibitor library, a stem cell signaling compound library, and an anti-cancer compound library.' That's five fewer. Now try and remove a bit more of the jargon.

Comment: @WS2 This depends a lot on context. If the intent is to stress the specialised libraries (think specialised promotional material) starting with them would still be better.

Comment: I thought you were supposed to avoid beginning a sentence with words like "Because", similar to how to avoid using "And" at the beginning of a sentence?  That's certainly how I was taught growing up.

Comment: nvm, some research has proven that I was taught incorrectly...stupid grammatical myths...

Comment: @Doc Stupid teachers (and schools, probably - and ministers too) actually. But, I agree with WS2 entirely.

Answer (score 0):

In all these examples, the product itself is not named until well into the sentence. You could emphasise it by putting it first. Unless you are restricted to a single sentence, why not break it into two, e.g.:

> Our bioactive screening libraries are composed of an assortment of ten libraries including inhibitor library, stem cell signaling compound library, and anti-cancer compound library, among others. They are therefore ready-to-use chemical libraries for drug discovery, drug target identification, and other pharmaceutical-related applications.